# Lubuntu 16.04 - How can I get rid of `nomodeset` on my old netbook?

Tags: lubuntu, 16.04, intel-graphics

My old Compaq Mini netbook with Intel graphics worked just fine in Lubuntu 14.04.  But when I upgraded to 16.04, I had to use `nomodeset` to prevent booting to a black screen.  At first I was OK with this, but I have learned that this causes a loss of functionality, like not being able to detect external monitors properly, and `xrandr` not working right.  Why did this happen, and is there a way to fix it?

Edit: Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`:

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27ae] (rev 03)

Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller [103c:308f]

Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A post on the Lubuntu Official Facebook group announced that this problem was caused by the omission of the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` from 16.04.  Installing this package regained all the lost functionality and allowed me to remove `nomodeset` from `grub`.